ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence in Flower Federated Learning
I am working on a federated learning project using the Flower framework. I have a server script (server.py) and a client script (client.py) along with a utils script (utils.py). I am encountering a ValueError when trying to run the client script. The error message is as follows:
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part. 
Here are the relevant code snippets:
server.py:
#...
def get_evaluate_fn(model: MLPRegressor):

    data = pd.read_csv('../data.csv')

    X_test, y_test = data.drop(columns=['ghi', 'dni', 'dhi']).values, data['ghi']

    # The `evaluate` function will be called after every round
    def evaluate(server_round, parameters: fl.common.NDArrays, config):
        # Update model with the latest parameters
        utils.set_model_params(model, parameters)
        mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, model.predict(X_test))
        accuracy = r2_score(y_test, model.predict(X_test))
        return mse, {"r2": accuracy}

    return evaluate
#...

client.py:
#...
class MnistClient(fl.client.NumPyClient):
    def get_parameters(self, config):  
        return utils.get_model_parameters(model)

    def fit(self, parameters, config): 
        utils.set_model_params(model, parameters)
        model.fit(X_train, y_train)
        print(f"Training finished for round {config['server_round']}")
        return utils.get_model_parameters(model), len(X_train), {}

    def evaluate(self, parameters, config):  # type: ignore
        utils.set_model_params(model, parameters)
        mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, model.predict(X_test))
        accuracy = r2_score(y_test, model.predict(X_test))
        return mse, len(X_test), {"r2": accuracy}
#...


utils.py:

def get_model_parameters(model: MLPRegressor) -> NDArrays:
    param = [model.coefs_, model.intercepts_, model.n_layers_, model.hidden_layer_sizes]
    return param

def set_model_params(model: MLPRegressor, params: NDArrays) -> MLPRegressor:
    model.coefs_ = params[0]
    model.intercepts_ = params[1]
    model.n_layers_ = params[2]
    model.hidden_layer_sizes = params[3]
    return model



I believe the issue might be related to how I am handling the model parameters in the utils script, but I am not sure how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Printing model parameters in get_model_parameters function gives:
Getting model parameters
Model params coefs_: [array([[ 0.17702605, -0.12339467, -0.10943707, ...,  0.06864394,
        -0.04777373,  0.10485562],
       [ 0.20891917,  0.1790593 , -0.16425643, ...,  0.07744386,
         0.12002279, -0.11625074],
       [ 0.18899827,  0.05276134, -0.04480367, ...,  0.0619819 ,
         0.04983299,  0.01192752],
       ...,
       [ 0.1623654 , -0.01042902, -0.01328439, ...,  0.06158556,
         0.04530179,  0.15687205],
       [-0.07160032, -0.13605067, -0.1132603 , ..., -0.21692066,
        -0.07970889,  0.16579558],
       [ 0.00537962,  0.05961771,  0.13938517, ...,  0.16319445,
        -0.07732371,  0.09838673]]), array([[ 0.06154933],
       [-0.16700333],
       [-0.00066868],
       [-0.12226686],
       [ 0.15384251],
       [ 0.09886249],
       [ 0.16242554],
       [-0.23517152],
       [ 0.08885664],
       [-0.04003581],
       [ 0.09174776],
       [-0.00939257],
       [-0.02750669],
       [-0.16627182],
       [ 0.15410905],
       [ 0.13208874],
       [-0.25548915],
       [ 0.03566291],
       [-0.05615016],
       [-0.16599462],
       [ 0.17656023],
       [-0.14453841],
       [ 0.22865225],
       [-0.11493084],
       [ 0.17523585],
       [-0.06211043],
       [ 0.18798979],
       [-0.1499165 ],
       [-0.02735363],
       [ 0.15048436],
       [ 0.11528322],
       [ 0.00890374],
       [ 0.21860512],
       [-0.00599137],
       [ 0.04835607],
       [ 0.10646817],
       [ 0.01499722],
       [-0.03204524],
       [ 0.02863824],
       [ 0.18944879],
       [ 0.24421394],
       [-0.17572741],
       [-0.20159749],
       [ 0.16916227],
       [-0.15225585],
       [-0.03453737],
       [ 0.11247354],
       [-0.06350287],
       [-0.13841577],
       [-0.08037083],
       [-0.04087836],
       [ 0.171563  ],
       [-0.1848397 ],
       [-0.04272012],
       [ 0.06560266],
       [ 0.18183274],
       [-0.0773459 ],
       [-0.18767521],
       [-0.19294954],
       [-0.11517002],
       [ 0.16628215],
       [ 0.18873195],
       [-0.20594848],
       [-0.10111657],
       [ 0.19617679],
       [-0.10317427],
       [-0.20045302],
       [ 0.17139839],
       [ 0.17000314],
       [-0.05239852],
       [ 0.02927883],
       [-0.07571771],
       [-0.13866223],
       [ 0.09295493],
       [ 0.10958947],
       [ 0.16702731],
       [-0.00756685],
       [ 0.01921512],
       [ 0.00743398],
       [ 0.24702312],
       [ 0.12260266],
       [ 0.01629527],
       [ 0.08824981],
       [-0.13488049],
       [-0.08172207],
       [ 0.16694024],
       [-0.14912095],
       [ 0.00795478],
       [-0.01370129],
       [ 0.12777411],
       [ 0.02691721],
       [-0.09549158],
       [-0.12955819],
       [-0.14541771],
       [-0.19125064],
       [-0.08114797],
       [ 0.11182001],
       [-0.1922918 ],
       [-0.04815903],
       [-0.01646154]])]
Model params intercepts_: [array([-0.18401587,  0.0555611 ,  0.15434747,  0.13350337, -0.04781075,
       -0.18747613,  0.13048155, -0.15274089,  0.09393277,  0.23531419,
       -0.23994224, -0.0032639 ,  0.08603195, -0.08943286, -0.07648003,
       -0.00655538,  0.10750902,  0.2524318 ,  0.06979107,  0.07963268,
       -0.18456307, -0.17754185,  0.05275503, -0.19627494,  0.23436304,
       -0.197949  ,  0.04849757, -0.20311904, -0.03834382,  0.06006001,
        0.17097278,  0.09229449,  0.21836487, -0.01836475,  0.20349914,
       -0.10136337,  0.12595533,  0.04273727, -0.18258228,  0.14785321,
        0.15617536,  0.03003948, -0.07050875,  0.15795615,  0.09310559,
       -0.06037786, -0.21369707,  0.12978744, -0.21044632, -0.18346185,
       -0.13003424,  0.10205835,  0.14351529,  0.22744359, -0.16485921,
        0.1771904 , -0.0034064 , -0.13114456,  0.18932282, -0.01096178,
        0.11604469,  0.02438452, -0.01849637, -0.16277839, -0.12166421,
        0.10804323,  0.18164772,  0.19586456, -0.06031436, -0.02473097,
       -0.17532117,  0.05817681,  0.15032765, -0.04234295, -0.11635163,
       -0.04664224,  0.04490203,  0.08041295, -0.04824706, -0.01387856,
       -0.13534482, -0.10684097,  0.07519688, -0.11615368, -0.22229584,
        0.02541333, -0.01876292,  0.07044277,  0.1287628 ,  0.17547035,
        0.1253518 , -0.09971929, -0.222933  , -0.13217835, -0.12161474,
       -0.02851148, -0.02147246,  0.04969144,  0.02717952, -0.12610586]), array([-0.05360869])]

Full error traceback:
ERROR :     Client raised an exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flwr/client/app.py", line 496, in _start_client_internal
    reply_message = client_app(message=message, context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flwr/client/client_app.py", line 98, in __call__
    return self._call(message, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flwr/client/client_app.py", line 81, in ffn
    out_message = handle_legacy_message_from_msgtype(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flwr/client/message_handler/message_handler.py", line 121, in handle_legacy_message_from_msgtype
    get_parameters_res = maybe_call_get_parameters(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flwr/client/client.py", line 214, in maybe_call_get_parameters
    return client.get_parameters(get_parameters_ins)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flwr/client/numpy_client.py", line 226, in _get_parameters
    parameters_proto = ndarrays_to_parameters(parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flwr/common/parameter.py", line 28, in ndarrays_to_parameters
    tensors = [ndarray_to_bytes(ndarray) for ndarray in ndarrays]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flwr/common/parameter.py", line 28, in <listcomp>
    tensors = [ndarray_to_bytes(ndarray) for ndarray in ndarrays]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flwr/common/parameter.py", line 43, in ndarray_to_bytes
    np.save(bytes_io, ndarray, allow_pickle=False)
  File "/home/zekynux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 545, in save
    arr = np.asanyarray(arr)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zekynux/PycharmProjects/Stage/example2/client.py", line 79, in <module>
    fl.client.start_client(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flwr/client/app.py", line 291, in start_client
    _start_client_internal(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flwr/client/app.py", line 503, in _start_client_internal
    raise ex
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flwr/client/app.py", line 496, in _start_client_internal
    reply_message = client_app(message=message, context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flwr/client/client_app.py", line 98, in __call__
    return self._call(message, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flwr/client/client_app.py", line 81, in ffn
    out_message = handle_legacy_message_from_msgtype(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flwr/client/message_handler/message_handler.py", line 121, in handle_legacy_message_from_msgtype
    get_parameters_res = maybe_call_get_parameters(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flwr/client/client.py", line 214, in maybe_call_get_parameters
    return client.get_parameters(get_parameters_ins)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flwr/client/numpy_client.py", line 226, in _get_parameters
    parameters_proto = ndarrays_to_parameters(parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flwr/common/parameter.py", line 28, in ndarrays_to_parameters
    tensors = [ndarray_to_bytes(ndarray) for ndarray in ndarrays]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flwr/common/parameter.py", line 28, in <listcomp>
    tensors = [ndarray_to_bytes(ndarray) for ndarray in ndarrays]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flwr/common/parameter.py", line 43, in ndarray_to_bytes
    np.save(bytes_io, ndarray, allow_pickle=False)
  File "/home/zekynux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 545, in save
    arr = np.asanyarray(arr)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part.


I tried running the Flower server and client for federated learning, but I encountered a ValueError in the client. The error message indicated that there was an issue with setting an array element with a sequence, and that the requested array had an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimension. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part.
I was expecting the client to be able to send model parameters to the server without any issues. However, it seems that the shapes of the model parameters are not compatible with what the server expects, causing the ValueError to be raised.
In order to fix this issue, I tried modifying the get_model_parameters and set_model_params functions in utils.py to ensure that the shapes of the model parameters are compatible with what the server expects. However, I was not able to resolve the issue and am seeking help on how to properly send model parameters from the client to the server in Flower.
